# Usage examples of "à en perdre la tête"

Tags: expressions, usage

I'm not fully confident of how to use this expression and its precise meaning. Can you provide some usage examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *à en perdre la tête* needs to be understood as *so much that it can be a risk for one's sanity*. It is then used in that sense, but of course as a hyperbole, to stress an overwhelming or unreasonable quantity or use.

Some examples:

> Il y avait un choix incroyable de plats, à en perdre la tête.
>
> Il passait ses journées à chercher des informations sur Internet, à en perdre la tête.
>
> Il est tombé fou amoureux d'elle, à en perdre la tête.

It is a variation of the idiom *perdre la tête*, which means "to lose one's mind".

> Mais enfin, pourquoi as-tu fait ça ? As-tu perdu la tête ?
>
> J'ai perdu la tête depuis que j'ai vu Suzette (famous French song)

Comment: Thank you! "Si tu veux bien ne pas me fournir trop d'exemples, à en perdre la tête." :D

Answer (score 1):

Google is a mine of examples;  numerous contexts of use can be found in the examples below.

*Extreme love*

- J'ai mis, comme on dit, dans ses meubles une petite ouvrière de quinze ans, d'une beauté miraculeuse et de qui, je l'avoue, je devins amoureux à en perdre la tête. (BALZAC, Cous. Bette, 1846, p.10)

*Sex*

- Mais c'est exactement ce qu'elle fit en se jetant sur son lit, ce lit où elle avait fait l'amour avec lui à en perdre la tête, et sur lequel elle versait des larmes amères et se sentait si seule à présent.

*Flirting*

- C'était une journée idéale pour les amoureux. Pour s'embrasser. Pour se cacher derrière les buissons et flirter à en perdre la tête. Wyatt retira son T-shirt pour améliorer son bronzage. Il jeta un coup d'œil à Annie.

*Sex*

- Elle voulait laisser libre cours à ses désirs les plus fous, quitte à en perdre la tête, quitte à ne plus être maîtresse d'elle-même. Respirant de plus en plus difficilement, elle se débarrassa de ses chaussures et chaussettes boueuses avant de …

*Extreme love*

- Il va bien falloir qu'elle tombe amoureuse d'un de ses cinq maris, songeait Jo en faisant les cent pas devant le cinéma, vraiment amoureuse, amoureuse à en perdre la tête, à en perdre le souffle...

*Sensual love*

- Complètement perdu, incapable de savoir où il en était. Elle était plus douce, plus féminine. Il l'enlaça et enfouit le visage dans ses cheveux. Elle sentait le soleil, le vent et tant de bonnes choses que c'était à en perdre la tête.

*Love motivated by beauty in the opposite sex*

- Je pense, comme vous, que madame la comtesse est bien assez jolie , assez attrayante, pour qu'on l'aime à en perdre la tête... mais à en perdre l'honneur... non ! — Encore une fois, capitaine, nous avons chacun nos idées.

*Stress*

- ... livré en pâture à la meute enragée des médias. Le moment était hélas mal choisi pour se mettre ses hommes à dos. Il avait besoin de tout son effectif sur l'enquête. Et mieux à faire que de s'énerver à en perdre la tête...

*Obssession*

- Consciente jusqu'à en perdre la tête de la présence du duc à son côté, la princesse fixait la flamme de sa bougie en pensant à l'engagement qu'elle allait prendre. Elle se refusait de penser au passé, mais elle avait en permanence à l'esprit …

*Stress due to self-imposed constraints*

- Elle disait vouloir perdre du poids depuis qu'elle ne buvait plus et s'imposait des régimes draconiens à en perdre la tête et l'estomac. Ainsi, pendant deux semaines, elle ne prenait que de la soupe pendant ses repas.

*Excessive drinking*

- Si vos hommes et vous n'aviez pas bu à en perdre la tête, cela ne se serait jamais produit. C'est votre faute si un homme est mort — votre seule faute. Ses paroles montèrent dans l'air froid de la nuit, et il se raidit derrière elle.

*Physical stress, muscular effort too great*

- Elle courait à en perdre la tête, à s'en faire exploser les poumons. Elle ne sentait plus ses jambes. Elle n'entendait plus rien que le martèlement précipité de son cœur, un battement sourd, douloureux, qui résonnait dans son crâne comme un …

*Excessive drinking*

- Nous nous jetions sur une table, buvant à en perdre la tête; au milieu de la nuit, nous prenions des chevaux de poste, et nous allions déjeuner à dix ou douze lieues dans la campagne;

*Love motivated by beauty in the opposite sex*

- Et une année de mariage s'étendait devant elle, à partager avec cet époux beau et sexy à en perdre la tête.

*Complicated things such as detective investigation*

- Nous, ça ne fait pas longtemps que nous sommes dans la région, et nous avons dû vite nous mettre dans le bain. L'enquête que nous menons, nous entraîne sur diverses voies. C'est à en perdre la tête.

Comment: I'm not looking for cookie-cutter examples just pasted from Google! That, I can do on my own just fine. Rather, practical examples natives will use in everyday life!

Comment: @Dasshoes Well, cookie-cutter examples just pasted from Google are the literature; doesn't it reflect life anymore?

Answer (score 1):

In English, it would be 'losing your mind'.  Now that's very much open to interpretation.  Just 'perdre la tête' alone tends to be pretty literal, to lose your mind while incapacitated in some way, whether drunk or senile, it's rarely positive.  But to do something 'à en perdre la tête' implies that you're willingly participating in this losing of the mind, and that tends to be a much more positive thing. An obsession whose consequences one may not entirely enjoy, but that has an overwhelming pull, that was arrived at through natural inclination.  Hence for instance the large love/sex section of google examples :-).